# Recover a Angular JS variable in a SF2 controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

I want to send an Angular JS variable Angular JS in my Symfony controller.
Have you any idea ?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);


app.controller("monControlleurAMoi", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {


    $scope.getMyXLM = function() {





        $http.get($scope.urlToParse)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var jsonData = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                console.log(jsonData);

}]);
```

I want to use jsonData in my Symfony controller

```
<?php

namespace LOL\LOLBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        // hello openclassroom.com
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use json pass to symfony Action. Try add in your action: `$data = $request->request->all();` to get all data post by ajax (angularjs).

In your case you should use extension to handle json for better, read this: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html